# How to start Splunk after installing

Tags: services

I search on this issue in many websites , however , if i found , i found tuto related to old versions :

In fact , Installing is done successfully  :

```
 sudo dpkg -i splunk-6.3.1-linux-2.6-amd64.deb
```

However , i don't know how  start it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea that the current version of Splunk create a `user` in your system named `splunk` with home directory is `/opt/splunk`

Thus :

## 1. Log-in as splunk :

```
sudo su - splunk;
```

## 2. Check the current directory after log-in :

```
  pwd;
  # must be : /opt/splunk , if so , proceed
```

## 3. Start the daemon :

```
   bin/splunk start
   # you will asked to agree the license =>  agree if you want to start daemon
```

## 4. Waiting for the following message :

> Waiting for web server at http://127.0.0.1:8000 to be available.. Done
>
> The Splunk web interface is at http://localhost:8000